# Clean special character in html using php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, goutte

i am using `goutte` in php to obtain the html of a page. I call php using `jquery ajax` and i put the page in a doc-area `(#doc)`.

I would like put that page without special characters, like `&nbsp;` and others, but my `clean()` function doesn't work. How can i solve that?

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once 'goutte.phar';
use Goutte\Client;

if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
  $url = $_GET['url'];
}
//client used to send requests to a website and returns a crawler object
$client = new Client();
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); //codice per accettare anche https
$client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/'.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
if($status_code==200){



        $result = $crawler->filterXPath('html/body')->html(); 
        $result=clean($result);
        echo $result;

}
else {
    //in case of error
    echo "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request";
}

function clean($conv) {
    $string = htmlentities($conv, null, 'utf-8');
    $conv = str_replace("&nbsp;", "", $string);
    $conv = html_entity_decode($conv);
    return($conv);
}

?>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function visual(search) {


    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "goutte.php?url="+search,
            success: function(data)
            {
                var content=$.parseHTML(data);
                $("#doc").html(contenuto);

            },
            //azione in caso di errore
            error: function()
            {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to decode the encoded html back to regular, you need to use `html_entity_decode`. That's all you need to do. Using `htmlentities` again on a html encoded string is wrong, as well as using str_replace.

Your `clean` function should therefore only decode the html encoded string.

```
function clean($conv) {
    $conv = html_entity_decode($conv, NULL, "UTF-8"); //To 'force' UTF-8 charset (php.ini settings may differ, that's why!)
    return $conv;
}
```

http://php.net/html_entity_decode

Comment: It doesn't work, in $("#doc"), i can see using string.charCodeAt(index), codes like 10 that are characters that i don't want to have

Comment: Add some `replace`to take care of these characters?

Comment: Dump the output of `$crawler->...`and the output of `clean` with `var_dump()`, if the output still is still html encoded, then your input has been html encoded more than once (or the input is corrupted).

Comment: `$conv = str_replace(chr(10),'',$conv);`

Comment: @Veve where should i add that replace? In my function or in Charlotte function? Before the decode or after?

Comment: @ScTALE Can you please post a sample of the html you get from `$crawler->filterXPath...`? (Edit your question)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois the document url is http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/brook/11brook.htm. http://pastebin.com/eFnsfwsg

Comment: === are mine character to make difference between $crawler, $result before and after clean()